# Контекстное меню в UserControl

Tags: wpf

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, можно ли как-нибудь вынести только контекстное меню из общего файла разметки в отдельный UserControl?

Comment: _Содержимое_ меню можно, по идее. А если само меню, то лучше в стиль, наверное?

Comment: Можете привести пример как вынести содержимое?

Comment: Ну, если положить содержимое в `StackPanel`, и выгрузить в `UserControl`. А в `ContextMenu` контентом установить этот `UserControl`. Должно пойти, по идее.